# VBA - InterSect, filtered rows, CTRL+D

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm handling `Change event` in Excel using `intersect` like this:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim WatchRange As Range
    Dim IntersectRange As Range
    Set WatchRange = Range("B2:B65536")
    Set IntersectRange = Intersect(Target, WatchRange)

    If IntersectRange Is Nothing Then
        'Do Nothing
    Else
        For Each b In Target.Rows
            Range("A" & b.Row).Value = "*"
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

When I change something in column `B`, it writes `*` to column `A`. And it works great.

Problem happens when I set the filter and copy some value to filtered rows using `CTRL+D`. This is my test table:

[image]

Filter only `text` in column `C`:

[image]

And copy number `100` using `CTRL+D` to all visible rows (column `B`):

[image]

When I cancel the filter, all the rows are marked with `*`:

[image]

It wouldn't be a problem in small table, but it takes about 10sec in table with about 1000 rows.

Is it possible to skip hiden files somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.EntireRow.Hidden` to figure out if particular cell is filtered or not. Your code would look like:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim WatchRange As Range
    Dim IntersectRange As Range
    Set WatchRange = Range("B2:B65536")
    Set IntersectRange = Intersect(Target, WatchRange)

    If IntersectRange Is Nothing Then
        'Do Nothing
    Else
        For Each b In Target
            If b.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
                Range("A" & b.Row).Value = "*"
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I needed!